# Xcode: File 'GameViewController.swift' is part of module 'SceneKit'; ignoring import

Tags: swift, xcode, import, module, scenekit

Recently I started a `SceneKit` project to experiment 3D in iOS.

But as soon as I created the project, 20 errors appeared.

In the `import SceneLine` line, a warning says that

> File 'GameViewController.swift' is part of module 'SceneKit'; ignoring import

I think It couldn't import the `SceneKit` and all of those 20 errors are relevant to this

---

So I created another project using `Metal` and it happen again. But this time it says that:

> File 'Renderer.swift' is part of module 'Metal'; ignoring import

So is it an issue for all Xcode Game templates or I'm missing something?

---

<sub>I have also seen this error in `SwiftUI` when it introduced by Apple, But I don't remember when and how it get fixed by itself.</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue has nothing to do with the template. A very common mistake that (I made too) is to name **the project** same as one of the using frameworks! (e.g. `CoreData`, `SwiftUI`, `SceneKit`, `Metal`)

## Solution

**Don't** name your project *same* with another module. Change it to anything else.

---

**Note that** It could be appear as error too. For example if you name your project `CoreData` and using *SwiftUI*, the error appears as `Circular dependency error`:

> Circular dependency between modules 'CoreData' and 'SwiftUI'

Because Xcode gets confused about modules and can not detect what the real issue is.